# Puppeteer close javascript alert box

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to click on a page button on [this website](https://portaleperiti.grupporealemutua.it/PPVET/VetrinaWebPortalePeriti/) but when I enter the site an alert box shows up and I don't know how to close it.

I just started experimenting with Puppeteer, this is the code I'm using this simple code right now:

```
const ptr = require('puppeteer');

ptr.launch().then(async browser => {

const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 800 });
await page.goto('https://portaleperiti.grupporealemutua.it/PPVET/VetrinaWebPortalePeriti/');

//This is the alert button selector 
await page.click("#BoxAlertBtnOk");

//This is the button on the page i want to click on 
await page.click("input[value='Perito RE / G.F.']");

await page.screenshot({
    path: 'screenshot.png',
    fullPage: true
});

await browser.close();
});
```

This is the error I get: **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement
    at ElementHandle._clickablePoint**

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: this may be what you are looking for : https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-dialog

Comment: I saw that, but I think it works with browser dialogs and not with javascript ones? (Follow the site link to see the alert box)

Comment: It looks like i misunderstood what you call "alert box". Alert boxes are usually browser elements, triggered by Javascript. Are you talking about DOM alert boxes / modals / popovers ?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote alert box because that's how they call it on the site selector. Yes, I'm talking about alert boxes/modals

Comment: I guess the issue is that the alert box has not yet appeared when you try to click it. You should wait for it to appear with this method : https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are few things going on that page,

- The alert box only loads after page is loaded (It has a `onload` property on `body` tag). So you should wait until network is idle.
- Clicking those "Perito" buttons creates a new window/tab due to the `window.open()` code put into `onclick` handler.
- The new tab redirects multiple times and shows a login page if the user is not logged in already.

## Solution:

### 1. Make sure to load the page properly.

Just add `{ waitUntil: "networkidle0" }` to `.goto` or `.waitForNavigation`.

```
await page.goto(
    "https://portaleperiti.grupporealemutua.it/PPVET/VetrinaWebPortalePeriti/",
    { waitUntil: "networkidle0" }
    // <-- Make sure the whole page is completely loaded
);
```

### 2. Wait for the element before clicking

Already suggested on other answers, wait for the element using `waitFor`.

```
// wait and click the alert button
await page.waitFor("#BoxAlertBtnOk");
await page.click("#BoxAlertBtnOk");
```

### 3. Optional, add few seconds before taking screenshot after clicking the button.

```
// optional, add few seconds before taking this screenshot
// just to make sure it works even on slow machine
await page.waitFor(2000);
await page.screenshot({
  path: "screenshot_before.png",
  fullPage: true
});
```

### 4. Use the `page.evaluate` and `document.querySelector` to get element

`page.click` will not handle all kind of clicks. Sometimes there are different events bound to some elements and you have to treat that separately.

```
// we can click using querySelector and the native
// just page.click does not trigger the onclick handler on this page
await page.evaluate(() =>
    document.querySelector("input[value='Perito RE / G.F.']").click()
);
```

### 5. Treat the new tab separately

Together with `browser.once('targetcreated')`, `new Promise`, and `browser.pages()` you can catch the newly created tab and work on it.

**Note: Read final code at end of the answer before using this.**

```
// this is the final page after clicking the input on previous page
// https://italy.grupporealemutua.it/FIM/sps/IDPRMA/saml20/login
function newTabCatcher(browser) {
  // we resolve this promise after doing everything we need to do on this page
  // or in error
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // set the listener before clicking the button to have proper interaction
    // we listen for only one new tab
    browser.once("targetcreated", async function() {
      console.log("New Tab Created");
      try {
        // get the newly created window
        const tabs = await browser.pages();
        const lastTab = tabs[tabs.length - 1];

        // Wait for navigation to finish as well as specific login form
        await Promise.all([
          lastTab.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "networkidle0" }),
          lastTab.waitFor("#div_login")
        ]);

        // browser will switch to this tab just when it takes the screenshot
        await lastTab.screenshot({
          path: "screenshot_newtab.png",
          fullPage: true
        });

        resolve(true);
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

## Final Code:

Just for clarity, here is how I used all code snippets specified above.

```
const ptr = require("puppeteer");

ptr.launch({ headless: false }).then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 800 });
  await page.goto(
    "https://portaleperiti.grupporealemutua.it/PPVET/VetrinaWebPortalePeriti/",
    { waitUntil: "networkidle0" }
    // <-- Make sure the whole page is completely loaded
  );

  // wait and click the alert button
  await page.waitFor("#BoxAlertBtnOk");
  await page.click("#BoxAlertBtnOk");

  // optional, add few seconds before taking this screenshot
  // just to make sure it works even on slow machine
  await page.waitFor(2000);
  await page.screenshot({
    path: "screenshot_before.png",
    fullPage: true
  });

  // we can click using querySelector and the native
  // just page.click does not trigger the onclick handler on this page
  await page.evaluate(() =>
    document.querySelector("input[value='Perito RE / G.F.']").click()
  );

  // here we go and process the new tab
  // aka get screenshot, fill form etc
  await newTabCatcher(browser);

  // rest of your code
  // ... 

  await browser.close();
});
```

### Result:

It worked flawlessly!

[image]

### Note:

Notice how I used new Promise and async await together. This might not be the best practice, but now you have a lead of what to look for when creating a scraper for some old websites.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you, I sure owe you a coffee. Just a thing, I see that when I run the script it opens my Chronium and shows what's doing... isn't hidden by default?

Comment: Ah, I forgot to remove the `headless: false`, usually I use that when debugging any of such problem to see what's actually going on. It's way better than being blind. You can set `headless: true` or remove it.

Comment: If I remove it or set it to true it doesn't save the screenshot from the new tab (or newTabCatcher doesn't run)

Comment: I see. So thats another issue. headless browser is surely a no go for your script, then. Create another question and I will take my time to debug that one. :) Sometimes it's not possible to do many things on headless mode.

Comment: In reality I was taking the screenshots to see if my code was working, I just wanted to enter the login form and then scrape elements there... Do you think it will work for that this way? (with headless false)

Answer (score 6):

If it's relevant to anyone else who facing dialog boxes, the following code solved it for me:

```
    this.page.on('dialog', async dialog => {
        await dialog.dismiss();
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Your button - `#BoxAlertBtnOk` will be appear on the webpage after a moment, when you call `await page.click("#BoxAlertBtnOk");` the button is invisible. Try to wait until it visible then take an action:

```
await page.waitForSelector("#BoxAlertBtnOk");
await page.click("#BoxAlertBtnOk");

await page.waitForSelector("input[value='Perito RE / G.F.']");
await page.click("input[value='Perito RE / G.F.']");
```

Comment: @astronomy-domine maybe the error has been thrown by next line of code. I updated my answer.

Comment: If I add the other selector it doesn't give the error but the taken screenshot still has the alert box open. It just seems that can't click on it.